# How do you do linearization Questions?

Tags: calculus

This is new to me, im trying to work on a linearization problem. I found an online problem

Find the linearization L(x) of the function at a.
$f(x) = x^4 + 2x^2,$ a = −1

What steps do i take to approach this solution?

Comment: 1. You look at the definition. 2. You think about it for a few minutes before jumping on the site and asking people to tell you how to solve it. (one minute ago you were allegedly "looking into" the Extreme Value Theorem; learn the material before jumping sideways to a different topic!) 3. You solve it by plugging the specific instance you have into the general definition that you read and thought about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linearization is $px+q$, where $y=px+q$ is the equation of the tangent line to $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$. Now I expect you can do the calculation.

It is not absolutely clear in what *form* you are expected to give the answer. Perhaps it is $px+q$, as above. Or perhaps it is $c(x-a)+d$.